# Select 5 Random Values from Array with Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can I select 5 random values from a predefined list for a query? Say I'm doing this:

```sql
DECLARE @colors TABLE (Color VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @colors
SELECT DISTINCT Color
FROM [dbx].[dbo].[SampleData]
```

But I would rather be doing something like:

```sql
SELECT RANDOM_VALUE() FROM ('Red', 'Blue', 'Orange', ...
```

Obviously this last block won't work but hopefully you get the idea. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM **QUERY** ORDER BY NEWID()
```

This will get 5 rows and order them randomly.

**EDIT**

Would something line this work?

```
DECLARE @temptbl TABLE(colour VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @temptbl SELECT ('red') UNION SELECT ('blue') UNION SELECT ('green')
SELECT TOP 2 colour FROM @temptbl ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I get it from a list of values I define explicitly?

Comment: Note there's no need to use union-ed selects if you're just inserting multiple static values - see my answer for example.

Answer (score 1):

Since the point seems to be avoiding permanent storage of a handful of colours, here are a couple alternatives.

It's ugly, but you can union a bunch of selections of static values together:

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM (
    SELECT 'Red'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Blue'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Green'    
    ... etc. ...
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

A better approach would be to stuff the static values into a table parameter:

```
DECLARE @colors TABLE (Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @colors VALUES
('Red'),
('Blue'),
('Green'),
... etc. ...

SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM @colors
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM Colors
ORDER BY NEWID()
```